# QA Testing Seminar Presentation - Suggestions please

Tags: test-management, team-management, quality-assurance, testing-team, qualification

QA needs technical knowledge and out-of-box creative thinking to be successful and demonstrations, meetings and presentations are critical to share knowledge and stay current. 
Can you suggest me some interesting topics for QA Testing Presentation?

Comment: The most useful topics I found were related to people experience in testing: what problems/challenges they have found and how they solved it. You could think of challenges you encountered.

Answer (score 2):

Below are some topics which can make an interesting story for QA testing presentation:

- Gamification Assurance
- Assurance to IoT
- Strategies for Big Data Testing
- Why should cloud migration be assured

Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

**It depends on the audience, really.**

QA, A person in this role is someone who consistently questions all parts of the process. So the presentation should cover all aspects of QA Testing.

These are the some interesting topics for QA presentation

- Testing Life cycle
- Test Strategy & Test Plan
- Defect Prevention (Take one project and explain)
- The Challenge of Effective and Efficient Testing

Answer (score 2):

Please feel free to pick from this list:

- Basic definitions of test terminology, such as black box, white box, grey box;
- Several methodology to come up with a test idea, such as brainstorming;
- what are the differences between manual testing and automated testing? Pros and Cons for each;
- Why automated tests will never replace manual tests? E.g. automated tests will never find random bug, such as easter eggs.
- How to estimate testing effort?
- How to track testing progress?
- How to review testing results?
- How to talk to a developer after finding a bug (this is never an easy task, people get very defensive when presented with their own mistakes)

Answer (score 1):

You could organize a reading club. At each meeting you could pick up one lesson from "Lessons learned in software testing" book and discuss it with others:

- Did we have same problem?
- Are recommendations in this lesson applicable to my context?

Answer (score 0):

QA Testing Presentation -

**Non-Technical audience:**

I would like to start with little brief about QA Testing. That includes,

- Definition, What is QA Testing?
- Advantages and Necessity/Importance
- Diff. types and Methodologies

**Technical audience:**

- Current QA Strategy
- How it could be optimize and what are measures of effectiveness?
- New effective tools available for Bug Reporting, Test management, Project management etc
- Scope of Automation Testing?
- Feasibility and Advantage of Automation.
- Suggest tools available and Its power + what level can be achieved?
- Time and Resources matrix to rise Testing quality with minimum time period